# Allowing connection on postgres flexi database for Azure to some application on different VNET

Tags: azure, vnet

I have "Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible server" provisioned with authentication
I am able to connect to that DB from my local environment
Secondly I have application on another VNET and VM which I manage and is again connecting fine from my local
How should these 2 VNETS be connected by following best practice, so that my app from one VNET can access source DB on another VNET (and region)?

Update,
[Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering?tabs=peering-portal#permissions) needed
please see attached
When I try to add peering for remote database hosted vnet, it expects me to have access there. This doesn't sound right, as same person dont have to access to both of the vnets. My access to DB is at postgres level auth
[image]

Comment: You can use **VNet Peering** to enable communication between two VNets

Answer (score 0):

> Allowing connection on postgres flexi database for Azure to some application on different VNET

To connect your application on `one VNet` with the **Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible server** on a different `VNet`, you can use `VNet peering` for
establishing a `secure`  connection between `two VNets` in the same or different regions.

Here are the steps to configure `VNet` peering between the two **VNets.**

1. To create a `VNet peering` connection between two **VNets**, follow steps below.

**Azure Portal > Virtual network > select Vnet > Peerings**

[image]

After configuring the `VNet peering`, please verify the peering status.

[image]

2. To allow traffic from the **VNet** where your application is located, create and configure the network security group rules for the **Azure Database for PostgreSQL Flexible server**.

After creating the **NSG**, associate it with the `PostgreSQL Flexible` subnet and then create an **NSG** rule to allow traffic from the `VNet` where your application resides.

## [image]

For more details, follow [Ms. Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-private) for a detailed explanation about **Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server** with private access (**VNET Integration**).

[Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server networking with Private Link - Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-private-link)

Comment: Thanks Venkat, so this peering need to be estalished at transmitter end, I mean at postgres service VNET side? I dont think any outbound rules need change at application VM side. Since source sql side changes is out my control, I will wait for that to happen and update here later

Comment: while adding peering for remote vnet, I got Failed message saying I dont have access to other mentioned vnet or linked scope. 
If thats the case then other owner of VNET may not have permission to my owned VNET

Comment: You may need Owner or Network Contributor, roles and also use the "Virtual Network Contributor" role on both the Vnets to peering the connection.